# oracle apex report row indent

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Can somebody give me a clue how to keep indentation in apex report like the result on this query?

```
select  lpad(' ',2*level-1)||ename as ename
from    emp
start   with mgr is null
connect by nocycle prior empno = mgr;
```

it look's like apex report trim all the indent tab and diaplay report as a usual row.

Thanx before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use spaces as indentation, try using the following:

```
select  replace(lpad('#', level*2, '#'),'#','&nbsp;')|| ename as ename
from    emp
start   with mgr is null
connect by nocycle prior empno = mgr
```

And change the 'Display As' attribute for the ename column to 'Standard Report Column' so it will display html markup

Comment: Thanx @Tom , i found alternate solution using : Report Attributes > Column Attributes for ?ENAME? > Column Formatting > HTML Expression
<span style="padding-left:#THE_LEVEL#px;">#ENAME#</span> thanx you :)

Comment: That is a good way aswell, i hadn't thought about that :) You should post it as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 2):

i found this one really useful :)

```
Report Attributes > Column Attributes for ?ENAME? > 
Column Formatting > HTML Expression 
<span style="padding-left:#THE_LEVEL#px;">#ENAME#</span>
```

Comment: Declarative! Very elegant.